# Put a list into an array in JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, list

I have a problem with Java: I have a list of integer that I want to put into a specific column and line of an array. For example, in column 1 I want to put [1,2,3] and column 2  [8]...

I tried something - I wanted to put the list into the array and then clear the list to put new values and put in another location of my array etc...

I created an array (RANG) of list and my list (ELEMENTS):

```
    List[] rang=new List[nbSommets];
    List<Integer> elements= new ArrayList<>(nbSommets);
```

I added some numbers and I put into the array ALL my list

```
rang[???]=elements;
```

Then, I clear the list to put new values

```
elements.clear();
```

But when I clear the list, this clear the list into my array too...

How can I do it ?

Thank you !

Comment: You have an array of (raw, cause generic arrays) lists. They’re just references. There’s two levels of weird going on here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
elements.clear();
```

with

```
elements = new ArrayList<>(nbSommets);
```

## Why `elements.clear()` clears the original `ArrayList` object

Because `elements` is still pointing to the original `ArrayList` object no matter whether you add it to an array, some other collection or object.

## Why `elements = new ArrayList<>(nbSommets)` will work?

Because it will disconnect the reference to the original `ArrayList` object and point `elements` to a new `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 3):

When you do `rang[???] = elements;` you are only assigning a **reference** to the array `elements` to `rang[???]`, you are no copying all the values in a new array.

What you have to do is, instead of clearing the elements array, create a new array (`new ArrayList<>()`) every time.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that if you create a `List elements = new ArrayList()`, you create a new object. If you put the list inside your array by `rang[???] = elements`, now your array contains reference to the List you have created. So your `elements` variable is pointing to the same object as as `rang[???]`. You can put it to array by `rang[???] = new ArrayList(elements)` and you will get a new List, and when you clear elements, the List in array will remain untouched.